# Apparent bug when combining jQuery Mobile, jQuery UI, and data-role=flipswitch. How to fix?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I've simplified my issue to this:

```
<div id='outer'>
   <div id='inner'>
        <label for='flipInput'> Active: </label>
        <input name='flipInput' data-role='flipswitch' />
    </div>
</div>
```

And apart from including those libraries, this script instruction:

```
$('#inner').remove();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lenoxus/f1oo4LqL/

The effect is to UNWRAP that "inner" div, rather than remove it along with its children, as I want/expect. It doesn't happen if the input doesn't have the data-role='flipswitch', which I really want to keep. (in other words, having that data-role causes the label and input to survive the removal process, which they shouldn't.) I'm going nuts trying to figure out how to counteract this.

Comment: @AWolff post it as an answer - my first comment was rubbish :)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "unwrap", but I am guessing you want to remove `#inner` but retain the content of the element?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise pulling out the elements that you need, `label` and `input`, destroying the created `flipswitch`, removing the `div`, adding the elements back, and initializing `flipswitch` on them again.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/2trwL715/

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var label = $("#inner label");
  var flip = $("#inner input[data-role='flipswitch']").clone();
  var parent = $("#inner").parent();
  $("#inner input[data-role='flipswitch']").flipswitch( "destroy" );
  $("#inner").remove();
  parent.append(flip);
  flip.flipswitch();
});
```

Comment: In doing some testing, when I run `$("#inner input[data-role='flipswitch']").flipswitch( "destroy" );`, I get the error `TypeError: this.removeClass is not a function` from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js (line 6, col 14872)

Comment: I seem to be explaining this very badly. I *WANT* to destroy the element. There is, at present, buggy behavior that unwraps instead of destroying.

No matter what, I can't remove the damn flipswitch or its accompanying label -- something in jQuery UI is "saving" them from being removed and adding them back in.

Comment: @Lenoxus you would want to use `$(selector).flipswitch("destroy")` to remove all the JQM elements that are added. Then you could run `$(selector).remove()`. But I think what you're reporting is that child elements remain after the remove is executed. Correct?

Comment: Yep. And that does give the error you mentioned before.

Comment: @Lenoxus will take a look. It might be a reported bug already. I will see if using a more modern, or even an older version has the same effect.

Comment: It looks like I may have found a solution. $('#input *').remove()